# Vector subscript out of range - C++ Vectors/OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

I'm writing a program that finds blue rectangles' 4 vertex and calculate the width and height of each rectangle.
It works fine with some images but others will show "vector subscript out of range"
How should I fix it.

My program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <D:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\highgui.hpp>
#include "D:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "D:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc.hpp"
//#include "D:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\text.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
fstream file;
Mat src = imread("TNR4.jpg");
Mat hsv;
Mat dst;
Mat mask = Mat::zeros(src.rows, src.cols, CV_8U);
Mat b;
Rect roi;
Mat gray;

cvtColor(src, hsv, CV_BGR2HSV);
inRange(hsv, Scalar(110, 100, 120), Scalar(130, 255, 255), b);
mask = b;
src.copyTo(dst, mask);//dst=藍框圖
cvtColor(dst, gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);

Mat bin;
threshold(gray, bin, 100, 255, THRESH_BINARY);

vector<vector<Point>> contours;

findContours(bin, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

file.open("GroundTruth.txt", ios::out);      //開啟檔案

try
{

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {


        approxPolyDP(Mat(contours[i]), contours[i], 10, true);
        file << "第" << i + 1 << "個框框" << endl;
        file << "Point(x,y)=" << contours[i][0].x << "," << contours[i][0].y << endl;
        cout << i << endl;
        file << "寬: " << contours[i][3].x - contours[i][0].x << " 高: " << contours[i][1].y - contours[i][0].y << endl;
        file << endl;

        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                circle(dst, contours[i][j], 3, Scalar(0, 0, 255), FILLED, LINE_AA);
        }
    }
}

catch (const std::exception&)
{

}
imwrite("bin.jpg", bin);
imwrite("result.jpg", dst);
//system("pause");
}
```

[the src image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZL9ZS.jpg)

[dst image and the txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucU4n.jpg)

the src image is huge and this is just a tiny part of it

Comment: Have you tried to use a debugger?

Comment: The problem is almost certainly inside `findContours()`. (since your code assumes all vectors returned by it are of `size() == 4`. Without that code, we probably can't help you.

Comment: @Frank `findContours` is from openCV. The thing is, I don't think it's always returning 4 points :)

Comment: *for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {* -- why not simply inspect what the actual number of elements that the vector has instead of assuming you have at least 4 items?  That would have been a good start.

Comment: add `if(contours[i].size()<4) std::cout << "this will crash or acces wrong values" << std::endl;` before the inner loop and test whether it will be printed.

Comment: @Micka it has not been printed

Comment: can you add it right after approxPolyDP? I missed that you access index 3 earlier